# Way to show db name on tables

Tags: sql-server

I use sql-server-2005,My database contains many tables.
When I explore my db, I see all table names are prefixed with "dbo". I want to replace the "dbo" with the database name  see below:

[image]

Comment: dbo is the default schema.  A database can have objects in it from numerous schemas if you want -- basically namespacing.  I don't see the point in creating a schema that matches the database name, myself.

Comment: +1 for using (and editing) an image to describe what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other have said dbo is the default schema. I'm not sure why you would want to create a schema that has the same name as the database, but to accomplish what you've asked you would have to do something like the following:

- Create a new schema using the [CREATE SCHEMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx) statement
- Move your tables from the default schema to the new schema using the [ALTER SCHEMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423.aspx) statement.

An example would be:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name ='iMature_US')
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement=N'CREATE SCHEMA iMature_US';
GO   

ALTER SCHEMA iMature_US TRANSFER dbo.PODetail
GO
```

You could write a script to transfer all the tables using data from the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx) view.

Answer (score 2):

dbo is a schema name, it has nothing to do with database name. SQL server uses 4 part names : [ServerName].[Database name].[Schema name].[Table/View/Trigger/SP/Function/etc Name]. Default schema is `dbo`, but you can name it after database if you want (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx for details)